# Set already hashed password for user against open ldap

Tags: centos, openldap, hash

Let me describe the infrastructure I am trying to configure. There is an opne ldap server on centOS (running slapd 2.4.40) as distributed authentication method for a couple of boxes.

Is there a way to modify a user (using ldif file and ldapmodify) to change the password with an already hashed? How to prevent the new hash not to be hashed again?

I had tried a lot of variations on ldif file with no luck. Any ideas ?

The hash configuration on ldap is :

```
password-hash {CRYPT}
password-crypt-salt-format "$5$%.16s"
```

Thanks!

**update** :

@Sven thanks for your reply. I tried your solution (I had also tried it before) and it seems that it keeps hashing the password... I changed hashing method too.
Workaround : 
assume I'd like to set the password for user `george`
 - change ldap configuration to SSHA

```
 password-hash {SSHA}
```

- restart ldap etc
- Hash a new password : (testpassword)

  ```
  [root@vm ~]# slappasswd
  New password:
  Re-enter new password:
  {SSHA}I5CTI/dn+ppf/XA/Jjz6yu+LRfPWqBQW
  ```
- prepare ldif file

  `[root@vm ~]# cat test.ldif
   dn: cn=george,dc=test,dc=com
   changetype: modify
   replace: userPassword
   userPassword: {SSHA}I5CTI/dn+ppf/XA/Jjz6yu+LRfPWqBQW`
- alter user using the previous ldif

  `[root@vm ~]# ldapmodify -c -a -f ./test.ldif -w 'rootpass!' -D "cn=root,dc=europa,dc=eu"
  modifying entry "dn: cn=george,dc=test,dc=com"`
- check if changes applied successfully

  ```
  [root@vm ~]# ldapsearch -x -w 'rootpass!' -D "cn=root,dc=test,dc=com" -b 
  "dc=test,dc=com" -s sub "(objectclass=*)" | grep george -A 3
  # george, test, com
  dn: cn=george,dc=test,dc=com
  loginShell: /bin/bash
  sn: Administrator
  sshPublicKey: ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAAAgQCr/fmBCVOx8io4dLnVeagN61ZW
  --
  cn: george
  homeDirectory: /home/george
  gidNumber: 33222
  uid: george
  userPassword:: e1NTSEF9c0s1QVRZYXVoSFpIdld5bzJTaVp0czlhVTFUNnJBdVM=
  ```

I suppose that the hashed password should appear on user password on search after user's modification, right ?

But :

```
    {SSHA}I5CTI/dn+ppf/XA/Jjz6yu+LRfPWqBQW !=  
    e1NTSEF9c0s1QVRZYXVoSFpIdld5bzJTaVp0czlhVTFUNnJBdVM=
```

After that I thought if it was encoded (Base64 for example)

But its also different :

```
    [root@ldap01-prototype:~ ] $ echo {SSHA}I5CTI/dn+ppf/XA/Jjz6yu+LRfPWqBQW > 
    test;base64 test
    e1NTSEF9STVDVEkvZG4rcHBmL1hBL0pqejZ5dStMUmZQV3FCUVcK
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This change operation should use a pre-encryped password (`1234` in this case). Note the `{CRYPT}` prefix, that tells OpenLDAP to use standard `CRYPT` libraries to validate the password, not the internal methods like `{SSHA}`.

```
dn: uid=johndoe,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
replace: userPassword
userPassword: {CRYPT}$6$NxKjjJP/Jlf$TrtCUMfi1uUpZDtYYvtFO2DlMsxntZ1ulzrTppJkqAZbX1Nv4WhdJ4vJbZcQDyWZVeGadtVQjqUHNZMT1FP8d0
```

Note: Using `{CRYPT}` is really only meant as a temporary migration aid away from `/etc/shadow`. It is better to use `{SSHA}` passwords with OpenLDAP. See [this](https://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/347.html) to lean how to generate these.