# OpenLDAP authentication troubleshooting

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am running an OpenLDAP service using the slapd.d/ configuration style. I am testing creating users and authenticating as user. Here's my test script, which ends with a fail: `ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)`.

`ldapsearch -H ldapi:/// -Y EXTERNAL -b "dc=foo,dc=bar,dc=nl"`

provides me with the user in question (among others)

```
dn: uid=testuser,ou=people,dc=foo,dc=bar,dc=nl
givenName: Test
sn: User
uid: testuser
objectClass: person
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
uidNumber: 2002
gidNumber: 2003
loginShell: /bin/bash
homeDirectory: /home/testuser
cn: TestUser
userPassword:: e1NTSEF9eGI2Y3ZrbVByd2lPT01HT0RQWFUyZitEYm5xdy9JaHE=
```

As a sanity check, I change the password using

```
result=$(slappasswd -s tree)

echo "dn: uid=testuser,ou=people,dc=foo,dc=bar,dc=nl" > test.ldif
echo "changetype: modify" >> test.ldif
echo "replace: userPassword" >> test.ldif
echo "userPassword: $result" >> test.ldif

ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f test.ldif
```

`ldapsearch -H ldapi:/// -Y EXTERNAL -b "dc=foo,dc=bar,dc=nl"`

again, and indeed shows me the password successfully changed:

```
dn: uid=testuser,ou=people,dc=foo,dc=bar,dc=nl
...
userPassword:: e1NTSEF9RTBnNDkxR0FPSzg0ZUt6M2dleWl1TWI3VHk1SURzekY=
```

`ldapwhoami -x -D "uid=testuser,ou=people,dc=foo,dc=bar,dc=nl" -w tree -H ldapi:///`

returns

`ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)`

What am I misunderstanding? If more details are necessary, I can provide.

For example, my olcAccess attributes are:

```
olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.exact=gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth manage
olcAccess: {1}to attrs=userPassword by self write by anonymous auth by * none
olcAccess: {2}to attrs=shadowLastChange by self write by * read
olcAccess: {3}to * by * read
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ACL rules deny 'auth' access to anonymous clients, because your {0} rule is not fall-through:

```
to *
  by dn.exact=gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth manage
```

If the request matches `to *` but does not match any `by` entry, then it will reach an *implicit* final `by * none stop` entry (sort of like iptables chain policy) which **will deny all other access `to *`**. That is, if all defaults were specified explicitly, the same rule would look like this:

```
to *
  by dn.exact=gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth manage [stop]
  [by * none stop]
```

To make the entire rule fall-through, you need an explicit `by * none` entry with the `break` option instead of the default `stop`, like this:

```
to *
  by dn.exact=gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth manage
  by * break
```

(For comparison, the {1} rule with userPassword is *deliberately* non-fallthrough, therefore it has a `by * none` at the end that expands to `by * none stop`.)

---

There are three modes for each `by` entry:

- `stop` (the default) ends the check completely.
- `break` exits from the current 'to' section, but keeps trying other 'to' sections.
- `continue` keeps trying also other 'by' entries in the same section. (They can be additive, e.g. granting read to one 'by' and write to another 'by'.)

Comment: It works, and this also solved a number of other confusing errors that I declined to understand at the time. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to put the type of hash algorithm used to generate the password, in front of the password value inside the ldif (to let openldap know that you already hashed the password). If not specified, slappasswd should use **{SSHA}**, hence you should set your ldif in the following way

```
result=$(slappasswd -s tree)

echo "dn: uid=testuser,ou=people,dc=foo,dc=bar,dc=nl" > test.ldif
echo "changetype: modify" >> test.ldif
echo "replace: userPassword" >> test.ldif
echo "userPassword: {SSHA}$result" >> test.ldif

ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f test.ldif
```

ref. [Set already hashed password for user against open ldap](https://serverfault.com/questions/948272/set-already-hashed-password-for-user-against-open-ldap)

Comment: The output of `slappasswd` already contains the hashing algorithm.

Comment: This did not work. This inspired me to also try `ldappasswd -s tree -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// uid=testuser,ou=people,dc=foo,dc=bar,dc=nl`, rather than an ldapmodify. This also succesfully changed the `userPassword`, but still `ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)`.

Comment: @Gerald Schneider, you're right, my bad...

Comment: @XGDragon, your steps sounds good to me. Even the ACLs.
Have you already increased slapd loglevel to see whether any ACLs are in the way
denying auth-level access to attribute userPassword?